# Xcode "new method" shortcut?

Tags: xcode, shortcut

My initial take on XCode is that it makes hard things easier, and easy things harder (find & replace requires way too many keystrokes, for example...).  The biggest one to me, however is a lack of a method wizard...  I tend to write lots of small methods, and I'm finding it hard to believe that you can't declare your method in a popup and have the interface and implementation files populated with stubs.  Am I missing something?  Frankly, I get far more functionality out of vi from an editor perspective.

Comment: Well, you can have both ;) http://www.corsofamily.net/jcorso/vi/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that exactly as you want it (without a plugin like [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html)), but it's not necessary, since you can create your own snippets, as highlighted in this [snippet question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303217/can-i-add-my-own-code-snippets-to-xcode-4), that will then contain the stubs you really need. Since most basic methods are written for you (or only require a few keywords to be autogenerated with your requirements, with @synthesize, etc...), it makes sense to me.

However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694325/xcode-possible-to-auto-create-stubs-for-methods-required-by-protocol-interface) could make your day if you still are unhappy :D