# Is there any easiest way to implement all required methods of protocol in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, methods, protocols, implementation

First of all it's not the duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694325/xcode-possible-to-auto-create-stubs-for-methods-required-by-protocol-interface?rq=1) because i couldn't find any discussion about offline documentation, suitable answers and about future release of updates in Xcode there.

Actually I am from android and java background and currently starting to develop iOS apps too. As we all know we use to implement all methods of an `Interface` easily with the help of suggestions given in **IDE** by pressing `Alt + Enter`.

And here in the iOS we have to see the reference each time and search for all required & optional methods, and implement them manually one by one which consumes times It's fine for a moment But

**My Questions are :**

1. Is there Any easiest way to view all required method at first lookup in documentation OR implement all required methods of protocol with the help of IDE ?
2. Is it possible that we will get this feature in future release of Xcode's update ?
3. I can't be ensure availability of Internet all the time, And How can I see the documentation at that time ?

Comment: this is not the solution but, i use snippet for mostly used protocols like `UITableViewDelegate` however it is not possible to create snippet for all protocols. I hope that XCode will have this feature in the future releases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just go ahead and declare that your class adopts the protocol in question.

Xcode will point the error if you fail to implement any of the required methods:

[image]

From the list  under the disclosure triangle (items with gray "!" icons), you can get a hint of the names of the missing methods. You can start to type and autocomplete will do the rest.

---

**Update for Xcode 9:**

It looks like now, you can auto-fill the methods with one click:

> Refactoring
>
> - Rename a symbol in a single file or in a project across Swift, C, Objective-C, C++ files, and Interface Builder files.
> - View all the possible changes in one editor pane.
> - Convert method signatures between Swift and Objective-C formats.
> - Update properties, getters, setters, and synthesized iVars as needed.
> - Apply a fix-it everywhere with one button.
> - **Automatically fill in missing cases in switch statements, and mandatory methods for protocol conformance with one click.**
> - Extract method functionality for all supported languages, along with other language-specific local refactoring.

*(emphasis mine)*

And indeed:

[image]

Clicking "Fix" adds the necessary method stubs.

Comment: Thank you very much !!I was trying to search required methods in the whole reference..

Comment: I couldn't find the Fix-it at first but this made it appear for me: If you see a red exclamation mark instead of a Fix-it then look for more information on the error by clicking on the disclosure triangle in the Issues Navigator. If you see something about 'Candidate is not a function' then remove or comment out that code first and then the Fix-it will appear.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Xcode` -> `preferences`(on top-left corner) -> `downloads` -> here you will see list of items that can be downloaded. Download the `documentation for iOS x.x` version. So now, whenever you are offline.. you can go to `help`(top bar in window) -> `documentation` and search for whole ios documentation.. all the development guides etc